# remoteFX support from Asus

Tags: remote-desktop

Does anybody know if
http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?p_id=swkakfpyg7h9al1h
 is a supported graphics card for remoteFx
I cannot seem to find a list of cards anywhere , just general chatter about how a bunch of vendors will support this technology

Comment: Have you tried asking ASUS yet?

Comment: well it was eitehr ask asus or ask serverfault, I think its fair to say I choose wisely :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not right now. Currently RemoteFX serving is only supported on nVidia Quadro Pro chipsets and AMD FirePros.

Best info I found is direct from nVidia:
http://blogs.nvidia.com/2011/02/it%E2%80%99s-here%E2%80%94nvidia-quadro-driving-virtual-desktops-with-microsoft-remotefx/

"Quadro 4000, 5000 and 6000 professional graphics cards, as well as the M2070Q server graphics module"

And ATI:
http://blogs.amd.com/work/2010/07/12/microsoft_remotefx/

"AMD’s ATI FirePro™ v5800, v7800 and v8800 Series professional graphics cards."

To date, MS has really struggled to package this whole thing into anything coherent, and the poor communication around it reflects this.